# AWS Elastic Beanstalk 500 error (Django) - Python-urllib/2.7 & static files error

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, internal-server-error

I'm currently deploying the Django & React Web on the Elastic Beanstalk, but I still get the 500 error. Is there any method to get rid of this error? I use PostgreSQL, and I grepped only 500 errors down below.

Here's my git repository:
https://github.com/ujin43255252/davidgram

```
172.31.1.112 (14.231.228.185) - - [18/Jul/2018:12:02:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "-"
172.31.1.112 (143.248.234.146) - - [18/Jul/2018:12:17:10 +0000] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
172.31.1.112 (143.248.234.146) - - [18/Jul/2018:12:17:10 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "http://davidgram.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/admin" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
172.31.1.112 (143.248.234.146) - - [18/Jul/2018:12:18:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
172.31.1.112 (143.248.234.146) - - [18/Jul/2018:12:18:29 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "http://davidgram.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
172.31.29.137 (31.184.194.109) - - [18/Jul/2018:12:18:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [18/Jul/2018:12:25:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [18/Jul/2018:12:25:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [18/Jul/2018:12:25:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [18/Jul/2018:12:25:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
172.31.1.112 (143.248.234.146) - - [18/Jul/2018:12:25:57 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
172.31.1.112 (143.248.234.146) - - [18/Jul/2018:12:26:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
172.31.1.112 (143.248.234.146) - - [18/Jul/2018:12:26:00 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "http://davidgram.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
172.31.29.137 (85.69.223.3) - - [18/Jul/2018:12:30:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
172.31.29.137 (85.69.223.3) - - [18/Jul/2018:12:30:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
172.31.29.137 (203.189.153.192) - - [18/Jul/2018:12:38:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
172.31.29.137 (209.126.136.4) - - [18/Jul/2018:12:54:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
172.31.29.137 (164.177.41.204) - - [18/Jul/2018:12:54:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
172.31.1.112 (209.126.136.4) - - [18/Jul/2018:13:04:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
172.31.1.112 (143.248.234.146) - - [18/Jul/2018:13:10:59 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
172.31.1.112 (143.248.234.146) - - [18/Jul/2018:13:10:59 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "http://davidgram.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
172.31.1.112 (177.189.145.3) - - [18/Jul/2018:13:14:41 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
172.31.29.137 (47.203.88.236) - - [18/Jul/2018:13:24:38 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.28) Gecko/20120306 Firefox/3.6.28 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
172.31.29.137 (31.184.194.109) - - [18/Jul/2018:13:37:56 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
172.31.29.137 (203.190.43.78) - - [18/Jul/2018:13:56:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
172.31.1.112 (179.55.191.177) - - [18/Jul/2018:14:38:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
172.31.1.112 (143.208.246.121) - - [18/Jul/2018:15:02:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [18/Jul/2018:15:19:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [18/Jul/2018:15:19:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [18/Jul/2018:15:19:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [18/Jul/2018:15:19:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
172.31.29.137 (37.26.87.166) - - [18/Jul/2018:15:22:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
172.31.29.137 (70.51.79.246) - - [18/Jul/2018:15:34:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
172.31.29.137 (70.51.79.246) - - [18/Jul/2018:15:34:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
172.31.29.137 (103.255.74.132) - - [18/Jul/2018:15:34:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
172.31.29.137 (37.63.239.222) - - [18/Jul/2018:15:42:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/601.7.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.2 Safari/601.7.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [18/Jul/2018:15:44:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [18/Jul/2018:15:44:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [18/Jul/2018:15:44:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [18/Jul/2018:15:44:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
172.31.29.137 (143.248.234.146) - - [18/Jul/2018:15:44:26 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
172.31.29.137 (143.248.234.146) - - [18/Jul/2018:15:44:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
172.31.29.137 (143.248.234.146) - - [18/Jul/2018:15:44:28 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "http://davidgram.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
172.31.29.137 (143.248.234.146) - - [18/Jul/2018:15:44:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
172.31.29.137 (143.248.234.146) - - [18/Jul/2018:15:44:29 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "http://davidgram.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: If there is any code involved, could you share it? And you've only checked the access log - is there anything written to an error log containing a stacktrace?

Answer (score -1):

I suspect if this is one of your first deployments, that you simply have not added the [Elastic Beanstalk hostname](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html) to [ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) in your settings.py.

But without the actual error logs, that is hard to be sure of. Using the Elastic Beanstalk console, you should be able to click "request logs" and then request the last 100 lines. One of the logfiles you will get from that is the error log, that has more detailed debugging information.